# C#: How to convert string into class to use in an "is" operation?

Tags: c#, string, lambda, types, expression

Assume that predicate.Or dynamically generates a sql where clause based on a list of strings. Is there a way to refactor this so that I don't have to hard code the case statements? Is there a way to move away from switch statement and refactor into a simpler/elegant foreach?

```
//contentTypes will ALWAYS have members that are the string class name of some classes in our project
//ex List<string> contentTypes = new List<string>{"News", "Photos", "Video", "Product"}

foreach (string t in contentTypes)
            {
                switch (t)
                {
                    case "News":
                        predicate = predicate.Or(ci => ci is News);
                        break;
                    case "Photos":
                        predicate = predicate.Or(ci => ci is Photos);
                        break;
                    case "Video":
                        predicate = predicate.Or(ci => ci is Video);
                        break;
                    case "Product":
                        predicate = predicate.Or(ci => ci is Product);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you have the namespace-qualified name of those types? If they are also in the same assembly, you can use [`Type.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-6.0#system-type-gettype(system-string)) or [`Assembly.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettype?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-assembly-gettype(system-string)) to get a `Type`. Then you can use `IsInstanceOfType` to check.

Comment: Though that probably won't work well with the SQL generator, if `Or` is dealing with SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely make it cleaner:

```cs
foreach (string t in contentTypes)
{
    Expression<Func<ContentItem, bool>> typePredicate = t switch
    {
        nameof(News) => ci is News,
        nameof(Product) => ci is Photos,
        nameof(Video) => ci is Video,
        nameof(Product) => ci is Product,
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected content type: '{t}'")
    };
    predicate = predicate.Or(typePredicate);
}
```

Another option would be to create a `Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<ContentItem, bool>>` and then just use:

```cs
foreach (string t in contentTypes)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(typePredicates[t]);
}
```

(Use `TryGetValue` if you want a clearer exception than the `KeyNotFoundException` you'll get from the indexer.)

If you have a lot of types to add, you could create a helper method to make the dictionary creation pretty seamless. But I would stick to being explicit about which types you *do* want to support.